# Flattening multiple querysets that share the same name in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have multiple querysets that look like:

```
NAME1 | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_1
NAME1 | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_2
NAME1 | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_3
```

How do I flatten this design other than using `list(chain(q1, q2, q3))` function because it shows up like this:

```
NAME1 | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_1  |                      |
NAME1 |                      | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_2  |
NAME1 |                      |                      | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_3
```

And I want this:

```
NAME1 | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_1  | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_2  | VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_3
```

As @Willem Van Onsem suggested I'm trying to elaborate below:

```
list1 = OrderElement.objects.filter(ordel_order_fk_id__in=Order.objects.filter(ord_status=2, ord_data_real__lte=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)).
values_list('ord_id', flat=True)).values('ordel_name').annotate(total1=Sum('ordel_ilosc')).order_by()
list2 = OrderElement.objects.filter(ordel_order_fk_id__in=Order.objects.filter(ord_status=2, ord_data_real__lte=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=14), ord_data_real__gte=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)).
values_list('ord_id', flat=True)).values('ordel_name').annotate(total2=Sum('ordel_ilosc')).order_by()
```

Basically I filter position by their parents date. That gives me output as:

```
list1:
ordel_name: OrderElementName1, total1: 50
...

list2:
ordel_name: OrderElementName1, total2: 100
...
```

Models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ord_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    ord_data_real = models.DateField()

class OrderElement(models.Model):
    ordel_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    ordel_order_fk = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    ordel_qty = models.IntegerField(unique=False)
```

Comment: It would help if you given an example of some model(s) and sample data together with the expected output.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did add more informations in main post, just now.

Comment: Can you share the relevant models (`OrderElement` and `Order`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, I did edit main post again

Comment: what is `ordel_nazwa`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Ohh sorry, it was supposed to be ordel_name, I changed it recently.

Comment: it is not entirely clear to me what you are doing here, you want to get the totals *per `ordel_name`*, but what is the difference between the `Order` and the `ordel_name`? Why is this not in the `Order` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Order model is a parent, it contains multiple OrderElements. I want to select all Order objects with ord_data_real in next week, then two weeks from today, three weeks etc. then select Order Elements that are connected to that Orders and list them week by week. Thanks to that I will know how many Order Elements we are supposed to deliver in next weeks, two weeks from now on etc.

Comment: so you want the number of orders, not the names of the orders?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want to sum ordel_qty of OrderElements that are childs to Orders from next week (for example). Categorized by name.

Comment: but is it possible that two `OrderElement`s for the same order have a different name, and two `OrderElement`s for a different order have the same name. It is not very clear to me what the name is doing in the `OrderElement` (element, not the `Order` itself)?

Comment: Yes it is possible in both cases. Look at it like they are simple Orders. ORDER: ID: 1, ord_data_real: 05.04.2023 ORDERELEMENTS: ordel_name: Product A,  ordel_qty: 50 pcs, ordel_name: Product B, ordel_qty: 100 pcs, ORDER: ID: 2, ord_data_real: 15.04.2023 ORDERELEMENTS: ordel_name: Product A,  ordel_qty: 75 pcs, ordel_name: Product B, ordel_qty: 210 pcs. So in week 1 i'll have Product A- 50, Product B- 100, in week 2 i'll have Product A- 75, Product B- 210.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work with a single queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

data = (
    OrderElement.objects.filter(
        ordel_order_fk__ord_status=2,
        ordel_order_fk__ord_data_real__lte=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=14),
    )
    .values('ordel_nazwa')
    .annotate(
        total1=Sum(
            'ordel_ilosc',
            filter=Q(
                ordel_order_fk__ord_data_real__lte=datetime.now()
                + timedelta(days=7)
            ),
        ),
        total2=Sum('ordel_ilosc'),
    )
    .order_by('ordel_nazwa')
)
```

This will make dictionaries with the `ordel_nazwa` as key, and two extra keys `total1` and `total2` with the number of `ordel_ilosc`s for the first seven days and the first 14 days respectively.